# Android photo in imageview, bad quality

Tags: android, image, photo

I allow user to take photo, and I get this photo to set it in a imageview.

This is my code for my imageview :

```
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
```

And my code to put the photo in this imageview :

```
        imgPhoto1.setImageBitmap(btmap);
```

My problem is, the photo is showing is blurred.....

How can I do to have a "correct" quality ?

I tried to use this :

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

but it changes nothing.

Thx,

EDIT : Please, I'm searching, if possible,  a solution without to use a library, it's just for two imageview..

EDIT 2 : Ok, it seems impossible to do without library, because my image take all of space available on screen.

Comment: Did you check this link:--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071007/imageview-loading-high-resolution-image-as-very-poor-quality. Possible duplicate.

Comment: remove `layout_weight` attribute from `ImageView`

Comment: it have nothing to do with library, but if the image is 100x100 pixels and you try to fit in a 1000x1200 View, it will get stretched and "blurred". You have to find yourself a way to better layout that.

Comment: @Nicks In your case, you seems to use a URI for the image. In my case, i have directly the bitmap. I don't know for the moment how to use this libs correctly :/

Comment: @deveLost : r u accessing that image from `drawable` folder

Comment: The user can take a photo directly on the app, and so I have this photo directly.

Answer (score 3):

This function resolves the problem of bad quality of a image at ImageView:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromResources(Resources resources, int resImage) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resImage, options);
}
```

And `imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromResources(getResources(), R.drawable.image));`

Comment: Literally SAVED MY DAY! Thank you! Wish i could upvote 20 times!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading bitmap use universal image loader or picasso for this:

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

[Why use Android Picasso library to download images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330772/why-use-android-picasso-library-to-download-images)

Comment: mhhh, i don't want to use a lib just for two picture... there isn't something to just have "little" better render ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AndroidQuery. It also allows you to load images async. I never had a quality issue with it. It is pretty easy to use and also allows you to cache images.

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 0):

change your imgview width and height style

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/photo1"
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
```

Hope It help

Comment: Hi, thx for you comm, but I need to have my image take all space on the screen available.

Comment: because u use a small size picture  displayed in a large view that cause the resize of the img. if you want to keep the  image take all space on the screen available then u need a larger size picture

Comment: I don't think so... the camera of my phone take a photo bigger than my image view.

In reality, I've two imageview on my screen. So the size of each imageview, is smaller than my original photo.

Comment: it seems the resize of the img causes the problem try this style android:scaleType="fitXY"